# My DFS can't handle simple graph [Python]

Tags: python, recursion, microsoft-distributed-file-system

Below is my code for **DFS**[Depth first search], and my code could handle complicated graph, but failed to handle simple graph like the graph i gave, so my Question is that how to work it out? I am doing it **recursively**.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
graph = { 'A' : ['B','S']}

def dfs(graph,start_node,visited):
    if start_node:
        if start_node not in visited:
            visited.append(start_node)
            for node in graph[start_node]:
                  dfs(graph,node,visited)
    else:
        return visited
    return visited

visited=dfs(graph,"A",[])
print(visited)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you representing graphs? If it is as standard graph (with 2-way edges) represented as a dictionary keyed by the nodes in which the values are lists of adjacent nodes, then your "graph" is not a graph at all since it is missing edge lists for `'B'` and `'S'`. But then, why are you using it as a test case? The only relevant question for such input is if you want to test if your code fails gracefully on them (yours doesn't -- but proper error handling is tangential to your question).

On the other hand, if these are directed graphs, then your example makes sense (interpreting the values as corresponding to *outgoing* edges and the keys are nodes which have outgoing edges). But in that case, you are failing to handle terminal nodes. You can either explicitly check if a node is in the dictionary before recursing on it, or treat the list of directly reachable nodes for terminal nodes as implicitly `[]` and using the dictionary `get()` method to return it in those cases:

```
def dfs(graph,start_node,visited):
    if start_node:
        if start_node not in visited:
            visited.append(start_node)
            for node in graph.get(start_node,[]):
                  dfs(graph,node,visited)
    else:
        return visited
    return visited
```

This will work as expected, printing `['A', 'B', 'S']`.

Comment: thank your for your reply, now that i understand, i really appreciate your effort and your time,cheers.